# Get the users that rate a video

Tags: youtube-api

I know that we can retrieve the videos that a specific user has rated as liked or favority via `PlaylistItems`. I could not found if we can provide the videoId of a specific video and get the users that have marked this video as liked or favorite. Is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot get which users liked or marked as favorite a video and the only information about it you can get is the number of users liked or marked as favorite a video, but not who did it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions, I just wanted to be 101% sure about that:)